# Android Emulator won't work on iMac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

In many attempts spanning months, I have never succeeded in getting the Android Emulator to work (with Android Studio). I've tried the x86, x86-64, and ARM images. I've tried different virtual devices.

In past attempts, the most common result was the emulator hanging and having to be force-quit. At other times, I've gotten "Error installing APK".

Today what I'm mostly getting is the nice picture of the emulated tablet, with "android" fading in and out on its black screen, while Android Studio reports "Waiting for target device to come online" (yes, I've tried the virtual power button on the control panel).

Using a Core 2 Duo iMac with 4GB RAM and OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan). The basic Android Studio 2.3.2 IDE runs fine. Running my project on a real physical tablet also works fine.

Comment: Does the emulator have enough memory?

Comment: How much is enough? And where is this determined?

Comment: In my experience, you need around 500 MB to get it to run at all. I use 2 GB to get it to run smooth, but in my experience about 1 GB should do thetrick. When you configure the emulator there should be a setting for it.

Comment: Mac Activity Monitor shows it using 965MB (with nothing running)

Comment: Try giving it 1.5GB. If you create a new emulator and press "New hardware profile" you should see a memory input. Change it to 1 or 1.5 GB, and tweak the other settings to whatever you like and your computer can handle.